# Java 7 : Does knowing a file is symbolic link or not helps?

Tags: java, java-7, symlink

In Java 7 it provides me a way to detect whether a file is symbolic link or not , but why anyone would want to know that .

```
Files.isSymbolicLink(target) //here target is a path.
```

I never needed that so far, just wondering what will be the use of it ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you're writing a recursive directory copy - you may decide not to follow symbolic links. Or maybe you're creating an archive in a format that doesn't support symbolic links - you may want to warn the user if you encounter one. Or maybe you're writing a `diff` program, and you want to skip pairs of files which are actually the same file really.

Basically it's a reasonably common property of some files in a file system - why would Java *not* want to expose that information?

Comment: "maybe you're creating an archive in a format that doesn't support symbolic links" i didn't get this

Comment: @AdonSmith: Suppose you're creating a zip file - does the zip file format support symbolic links? I *suspect* it doesn't, so it would make sense to warn the user, no?

Answer (score 0):

One really good reason you might care about symbolic links is because of security. Sometimes you might want to prevent letting people accessing files from outside a restricted area, so your app checks to make sure the file that is being accessed is not a symbolic link that leads outside of your application's sandbox.

For example, if you're building a network accessible application that runs as a user and that accesses files by path, like maybe a file sharing application, and you want to restrict where people can look for files on your users system, symbolic links could be a security problem.

Comment: want to discuss upon this point, i am giving an example from sftp please tell me if i am correct or not. Let's say I have an sftp server where people can keep files , now people can create symbolic links of my sftp file to some location which is not allowed accessible and can submit the file path to my location to let's say delete the file , my application will process and can modify the content of non-accessible resources . Am i correct or you please give an example.

Comment: Your application will be limited according to the privileges it has on the operating system. Your application would not be able to for example create symlinks in directories owned by root on a linux or unix machine for example if it's running as the user.